# How many (order of magnitude) Parachains can run on a Relaychain?

Tags: benchmarking

Does anyone have data/experience that indicates how many Substrate Parachains can run under one Substrate Relaychain?

I understand this will be hardware specific, so it will help if you can give some details about the environment used.

Example:
10-20 on an AWS instance type XYZ

Answer (score 1):

Kusama currently has 42 parachains, while Polkadot has over 30. These are real-world deployments on decentralized validator sets. Validators are recommended to have 8-core CPUs, large SSDs, and 16GB RAM, with 500Mbps+ network connections.

In orders of magnitude, the answer is tens or hundreds.